# wait bash-builtin burns a CPU at 100 percent

Tags: bash, shell-script, shell, signals, trap

Occurs at least on *GNU bash version 4.3.42 x86_64* && *GNU bash version 4.3.11 x86_64*

I use `sleep & wait $!` instead of a simple `sleep` for getting an interruptible `sleep` by a signal (as *SIGUSR1*).
But it seems that the `wait` bash-builtin behaves in a strange way when you run the following.

#### Terminal 1:

```
cat <(
   trap 'echo SIGUSR1' SIGUSR1;
   echo $BASHPID;
   while :;do
       sleep 1 &
       wait $!;
       echo test;
   done
   )&
```

#### Terminal 2:

```
kill -10 /the pid of the subshell, printed by the previous command/
```

#### Terminal 1:

```
^C (ctrl + C)
```

Then, I get the subshell that burns a CPU at 100 percent.

#### Terminal 1:

```
pkill -P $(pgrep -P $$)
```

Do you have any idea about why this behavior occurs?

**NB**: no problem occurs when the `cat <(/subshell/)` isn't in the background.

---

### Another way to experience this behavior

#### Terminal 1:

```
(
   trap 'echo SIGUSR1' SIGUSR1;
   echo $BASHPID;
   while :;do
       sleep 1 &
       wait $!;
       echo test;
   done
)&
```

#### Terminal 2:

```
kill -10 /the pid of the subshell, printed by the previous command/
```

#### Terminal 1:

```
fg
^C (ctrl + C)
```

Then, get a frozen shell.

---

### A third way to experience this behavior

#### Terminal 1:

```
(
   trap 'echo SIGUSR1' SIGUSR1;
   echo $BASHPID;
   while :;do
       sleep 1 &
       wait $!;
       echo test;
   done
)
```

#### Terminal 2:

```
kill -10 /the pid of the subshell, printed by the previous command/
```

#### Terminal 1:

```
^C (ctrl + C)
```

Then, get a frozen shell.

Comment: To debug this, you probably have to build Bash from sources and find out where it is looping (break it with a debugger or add print statements) and why it is looping.

Comment: Strange? I cant reproduce this here, i am using bash 4.3.42(1)-release (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu). Debian 8. Kernel 4.6.1-1. I do all the tests that you say but the CPU still running normally... I am doing exactly like you say including the fg, and then CTRL+C.

Comment: I remember reading that some things related to built-ins and signals changed in `bash` 4.4, maybe this here could be affected.

Comment: [Bash 4.4.20](https://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/bash/bash-4.4-patches/bash44-020) fixes a spinloop issue on `wait` that looks very similar to this. I was hit by that in a loop that spawned sub-processes forever. However, I tested your scenario on 4.4.20 and it was still a problem. Interestingly, when I attached a debugger on a version I built, I could see it was looping around, but it *also* had the effect of breaking out of it, and the loop would start outputting 'test' again. In other words: attaching the debugger made it stop spinlooping.

Answer (score 1):

**Observations**

- `ctrl+c` sends `SIGINT` to the fg-process in Terminal 1
- hence, executing `kill -2 <PID>` in Terminal 2 is the same as hitting `ctrl+c` in Terminal 1
- doing one of the two above points *before* executing `kill -10 <PID>` in Terminal 2 handles `SIGINT` correctly
- doing it *after* executing `kill -10 <PID>` in Terminal 2 (sending signal `SIGUSR1`) doesn't handle `SIGINT` correctly and leads to the problematic behaviour
- Replacing `kill -2 <PID>` in Terminal 2 (`SIGINT`) with `kill -15 <PID>` (`SIGTERM`) or `kill -9 <PID>` (`SIGKILL`) leads always to correct signal handling.
- executing `kill -10 <PID>` in Terminal 2 interrupts the `wait` builtin but doesn't leave the loop since `test` is immediately printet after the signal `SIGUSR1` is trapped and the loop continues.
- Sending `SIGINT` breaks out of the executing loop and freezes the shell or it never interrupts `wait` and stays waiting/frozen.

**Conclusion**

`SIGINT` is not cought and handled correctly or it is ignored after manually trapping `SIGUSR1` or maybe any other user defined trapping. That means that the process still exists and that's why it eats/heats up the CPU or freezes the shell. Executing `kill -15 <PID>` or `kill -9 <PID>` from Terminal 2 terminates/kills the process and gives you back the control over Terminal 1 and relaxes your CPU.

Why this problem occurs, still remains a mystery, but I hope somebody can explain exactly what is really happenening behind the curtains.